# How to extract / delete first word of each page?

Tags: vba, ms-word, extract, word-2007

I did a mailmerge to create dynamic word pages with customer information.

Then I did (by looking on the net) a macro to split the result file into several pages, each page being saved as one file.

Now I'm looking to give those files some names containing customer info. I googled that and I think the (only?) way is to create a mergefield with that info, at the very beginning of the page, then extract and delete it from the page with a macro to put it in file names.

Example: If I have a customer named Stackoverflow I would like to have a file named Facture_Stackoverflow.doc.

I found nowhere how to select, extract and then delete this first word from my page.

Here is my "splitting macro", which currently names the files just with an incremented ID:

```
Sub DecouperDocument()
    Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage

    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy

        Documents.Add
        Selection.Paste

        Selection.TypeBackspace
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\test\"
        DocNum = DocNum + 1
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Facture_" & DocNum & ".doc"
        ActiveDocument.Close

        Application.Browser.Next
    Next i
    ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below will enable you to extract the first word (and optionally remove it) of a Word document.

```
Public Function GetFirstWord(Optional blnRemove As Boolean = True) As String

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim intCharCount As Integer
    Dim strWord As String

    With ThisDocument
        Set rng = .Characters(1)

        intCharCount = rng.EndOf(wdWord, wdMove)

        With .Range(0, intCharCount - 1)
            strWord = .Text
            If blnRemove Then
                .Delete
            End If
        End With
    End With

    GetFirstWord = strWord

End Function
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi creamyegg. Thanks very much for your answer. I called your function in my main loop, but unfortunately got execution error 4608 : value out of range. Debugger shows the line "With .Range(0, intCharCount - 1)", do you have an idea what I've done wrong? What does it mean if intCharCount has a value of 0... ? Could it be because of the header of my page?

Comment: intCharCount should return the character position of the first whitespace character in the document. I think intCharCount would only be zero when the document is empty, i.e. no letters, words or whitespace in it.

Comment: It might be. The function I provided would only work on the document that the code lives in (ThisDocument). Looking at the code in your question again, try changing my function to use ActiveDocument rather than ThisDocument.

Comment: Then am I calling your function the wrong way? I'm sure my page isn't empty.

Edit : I just noticed the value of ThisDocument is "Normal.dotm". Shouldn't it be my document instead? I changed it for ActiveDocument but that does not work either because ActiveDocument is not always the original one.

Second Edit after your answer : to clear things up. With ActiveDocument it works the first time but on the second, ActiveDocument is set with the document I opened further in my loop.

Comment: Where in your code are you call the function? I think if you were to replace DocNum + 1 with the function call it should be Ok.

Comment: Works as a charm, I was just being stupid. Thanks for your time man !